# Windows occasionally thinks a modifier key is being pressed when switching in and out of remote desktop

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, remote-desktop

So I use remote desktop a fair amount of the time at work, and I'm running into the following issue:

Sometimes, when switching back and forth between my remote and local session (remote session is typically up on second monitor), after switching focus to the local machine, it will behave as if one of the modifier keys is being held down (typically either <kbd>Win</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) (so for example trying to type a <kbd>p</kbd> will bring up the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> projector connection menu).

Hitting whichever modifier key Windows thinks is being pressed several times is enough to reset it and make typing life normal, but I'm wondering if there's any solution to make this issue go away.

Comment: this is a problem with a lot of remote access software. Not just RDP. So I believe it is something hard to prevent since so many software suffers with it :-\

Answer (score 0):

Well after playing around a bit more, I found a partial workaround.

First off, what was causing the problem:

1. Start in a locally-focused window
2. Use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd><num></kbd> to bring focus to remote desktop session
3. Click on an item in the taskbar to bring focus back to local session
4. <kbd>Win</kbd> key is now stuck down

A workaround, which fixes the problem by disabling <kbd>Win</kbd> combinations, is to, when connecting, go to Options>Local Resources>Keyboard, and change "Apply Windows key combinations" to "On this computer".

[image: A fix]

This is an obnoxious enough workaround that I really don't want to mark it as the best answer.  Someone please find a better way to fix this :)